# save class variable changes with dill

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pickle, dill

I wrote an application with tkinter that uses classes as structure. Currently I try to implement a "save"-function, so that one can close the application and if it's restarted decide whether to start from scratch or to use already existing aka. pickled data.

I read about the pickle-module and its weakness that it can't save class variables so I decided to use the dill-module instead.

My Problem: dill saves the start values of my class variables, but if I let the user change the class variables (by calling classmethods), the changes are not saved. Is there any way how one can do this with the pickle or dill module?

I created a minimal example that produces the error. You can see that the changes of the instance variables are saved even after calling instance methods that change the variables. Unfortunately it doesn't work with the class variable and it's corresponding class method:

```
import dill as pickle
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# creating class
class Roomie:

    # class variable: total number of expenses
    num_exp = 0

    # init method: every roomie has a name, info for each expense, etc...
    def __init__(self,fname,exp=0.00):

        self.fname = fname
        self.exp = exp

    def raiseExp(self):
        self.exp += 1

    # class method: every time someone spend smth value of class variable num_exp increases by one
    @classmethod
    def updateExpNum(cls):
        cls.num_exp += 1

# saving instance of class in list object
roomie_0 = Roomie("Cthulhu")
roomie_list = [roomie_0]


def pickleRoomies():

    file_Name = "debts.pkl"
    # open file for writing
    fileObject = open(file_Name,'wb') 
    # write roomie_list to file
    pickle.dump(roomie_list,fileObject)   
    # here we close the fileObject
    fileObject.close()

# load all instances and class variables
def loadPickle():

    global roomie_list

    filepath = "debts.pkl"

    file = open(filepath, "rb" )

    roomie_list = pickle.load(file)

# create buttons and bind instance and class methods to them
button_0 = Button(root,text="update number of expenses",command=lambda: Roomie.updateExpNum())
button_1 = Button(root,text="raise expense",command=lambda: roomie_list[0].raiseExp())
button_2 = Button(root,text="save changes",command=lambda: pickleRoomies())
button_3 = Button(root,text="load changes",command=lambda: loadPickle())

button_0.pack()
button_1.pack()
button_2.pack()
button_3.pack()

# run GUI
root.mainloop()


# check program

# print instance variable
print("total expenses:",roomie_list[0].exp)
# print class variable
print("number of expenses:", Roomie.num_exp)
# print instance variable
print("name:", roomie_list[0].fname)
```

Comment: inside `updateExpNum` run `pickleRoomies`

Comment: BTW: you class keeps only two values - `fname` and `exp` - so you can create dictionary with both values and save it as JSON, or create list and save as CSV, or you can even save it in normal text file.

Comment: I don't see how both of your suggestions solve my problem. Why would I run pickleRoomies inside updateExpNum? The first is for saving the data, the latter for manipulating it so they both serve completely different purposes. Considering your second comment - The code above is just a minimal example. My original class contains about 15 class variables. I don't want to save it as a dictionary, because a lot of functions in my code rely on the class variables. I look for a solution that restores both my class and instance variables even after the user has manipulated the class variables.

Comment: you ask how to save data changed by `updateExpNum()` - so I say: inside `updateExpNum()` use function which will save it, and `pickleRoomies` does it.